# I can not scale my Canvas in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I can't scale my Canvas in unity. Where i normally do it, it like this:
[image]

I can't scale it or any thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As indicated at the top of the `RectTransform`, values are driven by the `Canvas` component (or the [CanvasScaler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.CanvasScaler.html) component)

According to the `Render Mode` you have selected, you are able (or not) to change the values. You may want to scale the children of the canvas instead of the canvas itself. If you have problems with designing your UI for multiple resolutions, I advise you to read [the documentation page about this problem](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html).

**Screen Space - Overlay**

The canvas is drawn after all the other cameras. Its dimensions change according to your screen. The scale does not need to be changed.

**ScreenSpace - Camera**

The canvas is rendered by the given camera, at a given distance from the latter. Its dimensions change according to the camera's rendering settings.

**World space**

The canvas is a "real" object inside your scene, treated like any other objects (culling apply, ...). In this mode, **you can scale** the canvas.

Source : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UICanvas.html

Comment: You can only scale canvas in world space. It's worth noting that you don't need to scale the canvas to begin with. You can just create a Panel under the canvas and use that panel to scale every other object.

Comment: Which of these options dictate canvas to be portrait orientation during design?

Comment: The canvas set to **ScreenSpace - Overlay** will cover your whole screen. If the latter is higher than large, it will adapt. When set to **ScreenSpace - Camera**, it depends on the settings of your camera (orthographic / perspective, viewport rect, ...).